# How to convert a single datatable column to csv?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

How to convert a single datatable column to csv?
I have a datatable that have two columns (Id,name) , how can I convert Id column to csv string?

Comment: @SonerGönül I tried by a for loop, but I want to know is there any way except this way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is the expected result? A string where each id is separated by comma or a string where the id is separated by new-line characters?

However, you can use `String.Join` + LINQ:

```
string result = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine, // replace with "," if desired
    table.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("ID")));
```

Comment: System.Data.DataSetExtensions should be referenced

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write to a file you can do this:

```
var dt=new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id",typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("name",typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add(1,"test");

    File.WriteAllLines("C:\\test\\test.csv",
        dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(d =>
                string.Format("{0},{1}",d.Field<int>("Id"),d.Field<string>("name")))
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can export using [Toad](http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-mysql/default.aspx) Mysql Or Oracle.

Also you can do this using PHP but this is depending in what you are after.

you can look into this [PHP to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22251961/export-mysql-data-to-csv-using-php)